# help with a sql query joining 2 many-many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce, aggregate-functions

i want help how to solve this sql problem. 
suppose i have 3 tables

### Movie

- ID
- Name

### Genre

- ID
- Name

### Movie_Genre (this one is the link for many to many)

- FK_MovieID
- FK_GenreID

i want to select all the movies that are of genre 1 and genre 3
how is this possible?
i can only select the movies of 1 genre but not the movies that are of 2 genres using

```
    SELECT Movie.ID, Movie.Name 
      FROM Movies
INNER JOIN Movie_Genre ON Movie_Genre.FK_MovieID=Movie.ID
                      AND Movie_Genre.FK_GenreID = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT m.id, 
         m.name
    FROM MOVIE m
    JOIN MOVIE_GENRE mg ON mg.fk_movieid = m.id
                       AND mg.fk_genreid IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mg.fk_genreid) = 2
```

The last line is key to getting rows from both genre's - the DISTINCT means duplicate associations (IE: two instances of genre 1) will be ignored because they are false positives.  But the count must equal the number of genres you are looking for.

But `COUNT(DISINCT` isn't supported by *all* databases. You should mention what you are using - if not by tag, then in the question... If the primary key for the `MOVIE_GENRE` table is both `fk_movieid` *and* `fk_genreid`, then it's not an issue. Next best thing would be that both the columns are in a unique constraint/index...

Comment: thanks, i will try it now. i been trying to fix this problem for several years now :)

Comment: also i coudnt pick a title that is more descriptive of this problem, but thanks for fixing the tags and the multi-multi to many-many :)

Comment: well it seems to work but i got the following error in SQL Server CE "'DISTINCT Qualifier' support not available in SqlCE.
Unable to parse query text." , but i think this is no problem because i have FK_MovieID & FK_GenreID both primary keys in the TAble Movie_Genre. i should have no duplicates Genre,Movie items in the table.

Comment: @Karim: Ah, yes - `COUNT(DISINCT` isn't supported by all databases.  You should mention what you are using -if not by tag, then in the question... If the primary key for the `MOVIE_GENRE` table is both `fk_movieid` *and* `fk_genreid`, then it's not an issue.  Next best thing would be that both the columns are in a unique constraint/index...